# ASP.NET MVC: Adding partial views dynamically and having them reflected in the view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Situation: I have an ASP.NET Razor page that is constructed of partials.

Some of these are in loops iterating over collections that are members of the main page's view model. These iterated partials use the collections' member types as their own view model.

So the main page Razor looks something like this:

```
@model MyProject.MainViewModel

@*Other stuff...*@

@foreach (Subtype v in Model.SubViewModel)
{
         Html.RenderPartial("MyPartial", v);
}
```

And the partial looks like this:

```
@model Subtype 

@Html.HiddenFor(t=>t.ParentViewModelID)

@Html.EditorFor(t=>t.Field1)
@Html.EditorFor(t=>t.Field2)
```

This all works well on initial page load, but I'm wondering how I should handle ***dynamically adding these partials via AJAX***.

Suppose the user presses a button that's ultimately intended to add to one of these view model collections. I can AJAX back to the server, render the appropriate partial there, and return it to the client:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddSubtype(int mainViewModelId)
{
  var model = new Sub { ParentViewModelID=mainViewModelId};
  return PartialView("MyPartial", model);
}
```

And then I use a bit of script to stick this into the DOM where it belongs:

```
 success: (data) => {  $('#subtypeHanger').append(data);},
```

This seems to work, except for one big part: when I evntually submit my form, I'm not seeing the data associated with this dynamically added partial in my view model.

I have been trying to debug this, but I'm wondering in broad terms whether this is possible- or alternately, how much MVC is supposed to abstract over such things. Obviously I can do things with JavaScript to force this to work. Is there an ASP.NET MVC pattern for this I should emulate, though?

---

EDIT: I'll mention some things I've tried since I posted this:

1. Managing the "name" and "id" attributes of the partial views' edit controls manually, so that they end up looking like they do when I nest these controls in the main view instead of a partial (i.e. longer, with more text and an index).
2. Using the main view model class for the partials. This makes me move the loops into the partial. The "name" and "id" property look like what I was going for in #1 above, but this design greatly complicates the process of returning the partial from my AJAX calls.
3. Using "for" loops instead of "foreach." By itself, this doesn't achieve what I want.

All this said, if #1 or #2 is the best pattern for what I'm doing, perhaps I can make that work.

Comment: Whats the `name` attribute of the dynamically added form fields (t.Field1, etc). Thats what the model binder uses to bind data to your view model on post/submit. It looks like `Model.SubViewModel` is a list, so when they get added in the loop they probably have list index postions (i.e. `name="SubViewModel[0]_Field1"`) but when you add dynamically, since its not in a list it renders out like this: `name="Field1"` so it doesn't map properly when you submit

Comment: @zgood Thanks, and that's 100% correct: the name fields are simple, unindexed values like "Field1." So I guess that's what I need to attack. If I move my "for" loop inside the partial, I think that might help... but then I can't really add that partial dynamically, since it's for the whole collection. Do I need yet another, innermost partial? Do I need to manage "name" myself somehow? Thanks!!

Comment: You are dynamically adding them, are you also going to be dynamically removing them via ajax calls? If so managing the list item indices can be annoying (i.e. in a list of 3 if #2 gets removed then `SubViewModel[2]_Field1` needs to be come `SubViewModel[1]_Field1` to bind properly). Usually I find the best way of doing this is creating a javascript function the loops thru the `inputs` and make sure the `name` attributes are correct - has right list name prefix (i.e `SubViewModel`) and that the index is correct. Then call the function after every ajax add and remove action

Comment: OK @zgood, that's helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Its important to realize that when you submit the ajax call because mvc is stateless mvc has no prior knowledge of the state changes on the server up until that point so mvc will have no way of returning the correct values for the name attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### "Situation: I have an ASP.NET Razor page that is constructed of partials."

- This is called "Master Details"

  - check 
    [Master Details CRUD with MVC 5 | The ASP.NET Forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2136546.aspx?Master+Details+CRUD+with+MVC+5)

- The trick is naming your Fields

  ```
  @Html.HiddenFor(t=>t.ParentViewModelID ,new { htmlAttributes = new { @Name = "[" + i + "].ParentViewModelID" } })
  @Html.EditorFor(t=>t.Field1 ,new { htmlAttributes = new { @Name = "[" + i + "].Field1" } })
  @Html.EditorFor(t=>t.Field2 , new { htmlAttributes = new { @Name = "[" + i + "].Field2" } })
  ```
- so it will be

  ```
  <input type="text" name="[0].Field1" />
  <input type="text" name="[0].Field2" />
  <input type="text" name="[1].Field1" />
  <input type="text" name="[1].Field2" />
  ```
- and better(for ASP.NET mvc 5 Model Binding) if you use

  ```
  public ActionResult Edit(MainViewModel master, List<Subtype> details)
  ```

### if you provided the Full model i will provide a full working example

Comment: Thanks. It does seem that manually managing "name" is the only way to do this. I had not quite been able to get it right on my own, though, so your example is helpful. It's also good to get some confirmation that there's not some out-of-the-box magic that handles this.

Comment: @user1172763 if you provided the Full model i will provide a full working example